# Typescript doesn't catch wrong type in react sub component

Tags: typescript, react-redux

React reducer:

```
export interface ParamObj {
    count: number;
    offset: number;
}
...
```

Then, I have a component:

```
import { ParamObj } from "./MyReducer";

interface ParentProps {
    params: ParamObj;
    handleClick: () => void;
}
class ParentComp extends React.Component<ParentProps, {}> {
    render() {
        return <ChildComp offset={this.props.params.offset} />;
    }
}
```

In the subcomponent, I have:

```
interface ChildProps {
    offset: string;
}
class ChildComp extends React.Component<ChildProps, {}> {
    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.offset}</div>
    }
}
```

The problem is that the subcomponent doesn't throw an error even though the param1 type doesn't match the type from the parent component. The expected behavior is that it should say the SubComponent param1 expects a number, but the prop type is a string.

How can I get it to recognize the type from the parent component?

EDIT:
Added complete code.

Comment: I can help you investigate the original problem (lack of an error) if you provide code sufficient to reproduce the problem (e.g., both component classes).

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I modified the description. As you can see, the ChildComp expects a string for "offset," but the ParentComp is a number. This doesn't throw an error in typescript unless I modify the ChildProps to be "offset: ParamObj['offset'];"

Comment: Your code gives me two errors: (1) the `const { offset } = this.props;` needs to be moved inside `render` and (2) `ParentProps` is not defined.  When I fix #1 and change `ParentProps` to `ParamObj`, then I get the expected error on the `offset` attribute, `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.`.  So the code you posted does not seem to be reproducing the problem.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen oops, I had a typos/wrong placements in the code sample. Hmm, so it seems like if the corrected code works, is there some setting that I could be missing? This is part of a very large project so I can't paste it here. But that's essentially what's happening for the Parent/Child component.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen Sorry, I updated the code sample since it looks like it was changed in the code. Does the new sample still work for you? If not, is it the way that it's now set up?

Comment: I pasted the new code sample into a file in a new project and added the React import and I still get the expected error, `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.`  You can try this yourself.  There must be something different about your original large project.  If you want to track down the issue, you'll have to either do it yourself or make a copy of the project and remove irrelevant code until you're left with a complete project that reproduces the problem that you're willing to share.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen okay, thanks! I will have to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I don't know why TS works this way, but it turns out I needed to do:

```
interface SubCompProps {
    param1: ParamObj["param1"];
}
```